# Winforms dataset X sql ce 4

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

How can I use Windows forms dataset and sql server CE 4 ? I'm trying to drop tables from server-explorer to the dataset and getiing this message:

[image]

Is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that combination is not currently supported.